Yum update package awscli requries python3
I have an EC2 instance with Rocky Linux 9 (Official) - x86_64 and Cpanel installed. I'm receiving notifications daily about this issue when the system tries to update packages or when I run /scripts/update-package. The error that shows up:
Error:
 Problem: package awscli-1.23.10-3.el9.noarch from @System requires python3.9dist(botocore) = 1.25.10, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both python3-botocore-1.31.62-1.el9.noarch from appstream and python3-botocore-1.25.10-1.el9.noarch from @System
  - cannot install both python3-botocore-1.31.62-1.el9.noarch from appstream and python3-botocore-1.25.10-1.el9.noarch from epel
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-botocore-1.25.10-1.el9.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package awscli-1.23.10-3.el9.noarch
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
(XID n4qjt3) “/usr/bin/yum” reported error code “1” when it ended:

I tried to add this package to /etc/yum.conf at the end of the exclude line:
[main]
exclude=bind-chroot dovecot* exim* filesystem p0f php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* awscli*

but I still get the same failure notification every day.
Is there a way to update or disable the package not to update automatically?

Ask Cpanel support how to fix their crap, you paid for it.

You should use AWS CLI v2 instead.
Unfortunately, all distributions I encountered except for Amazon Linux offer a AWS CLI v1 package only. So:

remove the awscli package

and install AWS CLI v2:
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install



Will solve your current problem as a side effect and prevent lots of problems in the future.
